# Getting the name of a location from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am a dummy in android app development. I have developed an app that when a button is clicked, the google maps application opens. I want to get the name of the location that has been selected in the google maps application and use it in my own application. Is it possible to do so? Plus, can it be done without integrating google maps or google places API in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the "Start activity for result" construct. With that, and some data in an intent, you can request a location like that from Google Maps.

I would also recommend allowing a person to share a location from Maps to your app. Depending on what your app would be doing with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location name from the point you clicked on a map. 
You can do it using the device to query into the Google Map Api or you can write a rest service where you pass in your location and the service hand you back the location name.